# Use .obj and .max files in AndEngine for Android games

Tags: android, andengine

I am working in a game which is using **AndEngine** to develop.I successfully use *.jpg* and *.png* files in this.But I face too much problems when I trying to use ***Maya*** Animated files (which are in *.max* extension) and also *.obj* files. Can anyone please suggest me how can I use *.max* files. Or at least *.obj* files in my programs.Hope everyone understand my problem clearly. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure: But AndEngine is a 2D game-engine while *.max* and *.obj* files usually describe 3D object/animations. For example obj files can contain vertexes, while AndEngine is not capable of using vertexes directly (although, some extensions might).

What I am sure of: you can always make little screenshots of your Maya animation and put them all in a row in a png file and use the png image instead.